# Ask Firefox to export current Bookmarks to Json in CMD line

Tags: command-line, firefox, bookmarks

I can do this manually in Firefox when the browser is open *(holding Alt key to show menu)* and navigating to

```
Bookmarks > Show All Bookmarks > Import And Backup > Backup
```

This will generate a timestap json file.

However I want to Achieve this same json file but via the **Command Line**.

I am aware I can navigate to

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\4jrnk45.default\bookmarkbackups\
```

However the problem is the files present in this folder can be outdated - Including the most recent file, I confirmed this by checking the contents of the most recent backup file in this folder and comparing to a manually generated json file, the json file contains more bookmarks, so this way is **not** a method. Unless we can tell Firefox to update this folder when we choose.

Comment: The bookmarks appear to be stored in 4jrnk45.default\places.sqlite, so you could generate the data with an SQL query. and then format it into JSON. Does not answer your question though.

Comment: @glennjackman I guess thats one alternative, il keep it in mind, thanks